# Rotation animation for the background gradient of the view

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

I want to add an animation to my app where I want the background gradient of my screen to rotate. I have tried a few things like ValueAnimator, PropertyAnimator etc but I am facing a problem.

When I run my animation the entire view starts rotating. It looks like the screen itself is rotating. Instead I want an effect where only the background gradient rotates not the entire screen.

What is the best way to get such effect?

Here is what I have so far

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val view: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.animation_view)
        startAnimation(view)
    }

    private fun startAnimation(view: View) {
        view.startAnimation(
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                this, R.anim.rotation_clockwise
            )
        )
    }
}
```

animation resource xml

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="1200"/>
```

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPurple_A400"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_purple_gradient">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you animate the root view of the `activity` or `fragment`?
If yes, that makes sense. The whole screen will be rotated.

If you want to animate the background of the view, you should add a new view which holds only the background then rotate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/colorPurple_A400"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <View
    android:id="@+id/animation_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_purple_gradient"/>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that, but still the same result. I have added my layout file in the question.

Comment: @Ezio I updated my answer and used your layout file

Comment: I tried your solution but I am still getting the same result.

Comment: If you are animating the view which it's id is `animation_view` How are all views animate? that doesn't make sense